# Python Error: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables, compiler-errors

Here is my code:

```
import time

GLO = time.time()

def Test():
    print GLO
    temp = time.time();
    print temp
    GLO = temp

Test()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 11, in
>   
>       Test()   File "test.py", line 6, in Test
>       print GLO UnboundLocalError: local variable 'GLO' referenced before assignment

the error occurred when I add the `GLO = temp`, if I comment it, the function could be execute successfully, why?

How can I set `GLO = temp`?

Answer (score 5):

Within the Test method specify that you want to refer to the globally declared GLO variable  as shown below

```
def Test():
    global GLO #tell python that you are refering to the global variable GLO declared earlier.
    print GLO
    temp = time.time();
    print temp
    GLO = temp
```

A similar question can be found here :
[Using a global variable within a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Answer (score 4):

Python looks the whole function scope first. So your `GLO` refers to the one below, not the global one. And refer the [LEGB rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules).

```
GLO = time.time()

def Test(glo):
    print glo
    temp = time.time();
    print temp
    return temp

GLO = Test(GLO)
```

or

```
GLO = time.time()

def Test():
    global GLO
    print GLO
    temp = time.time();
    print temp
    GLO =  temp

Test()
```